# Android post a JSon object to WCF receiving null

Tags: android, json, wcf, post

I having a problem with my android client trying to post a JSON class to my wcf service. 
Wcf is receiving the post, but the parameter is null

Here is the code for android client :

```
private void EnviaDados( DadosUsuario usuario, String fileName, String pAssunto, String pComentario, String pOnde, String pQuando ) throws Exception
{

    fileName = fileName.substring( fileName.indexOf("$$$")+3 , fileName.length() );
    fileName = fileName.substring( 0, fileName.indexOf("$$$") );

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url = "http://192.168.1.112/WCF2/UploadService.svc/REST/ArqInfoAndroid";

    String pNome = usuario.RetornaDados()[0];
    String pDDD = usuario.RetornaDados()[1];
    String pTelefone = usuario.RetornaDados()[2];
    String pEmail = usuario.RetornaDados()[3];
    String pRegiao = usuario.RetornaDados()[4];

    try {

        URI uri = new URI(url);

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uri);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(retornaJson(pNome, pEmail, pDDD,pTelefone, pRegiao, fileName, pComentario, pOnde, pAssunto, pQuando).toString());

        postRequest.setEntity(se);

        postRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        postRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        int staCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 

        if (staCode == 200 || staCode == 400) {

            InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                String res = convertStreamToString(instream);

                if(res.contains(("FALHA")))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Falha ao enviar arquivo"); 
                }

        } 

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (URISyntaxException e){ 
    } 

}


public  JSONStringer retornaJson(String nome, String email, String ddd, String telefone, String regiao, String arquivo, String comentario, String onde, String assunto, String quando)
{
     JSONStringer DadosUsu = new JSONStringer();
     try
     {
          DadosUsu.object()
                 .key("DadosUsuario").object().key("Nome")
                 .value(nome).key("Email")
                 .value(email).key("DDD")
                 .value(ddd).key("Telefone")
                 .value(telefone).key("Regiao")
                 .value(regiao).key("NomeArq")
                 .value(arquivo).key("Comentario")
                 .value(comentario).key("Onde")
                 .value(onde).key("Assunto")
                 .value(assunto).key("Quando")
                 .value(quando).endObject().endObject();

     }
     catch (Exception je)
     {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     }  

     return DadosUsu;
}
```

Here is code for Wcf **(the parameter dadosUsuario is null)**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "ArqInfoAndroid")]
    public string ArqInfoAndroid(DadosUsu dadosUsuario)
    {

        EscreverNoLog("Recebendo dados usuário Android");

        try
        {

            string absFileName = string.Format("{0}\\FileUpload\\{1}"
                                    , AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                                    , dadosUsuario.NomeArq);


            GerenciaThread pTh = new GerenciaThread();


            EscreverNoLog("Recebendo dados usuário Android: " +
                            dadosUsuario.Nome + " - " +
                            dadosUsuario.Email + " - " +
                            dadosUsuario.DDD + " - " +
                            dadosUsuario.Telefone + " - " +
                            dadosUsuario.Regiao + " - " +
                            absFileName + " - " +
                            dadosUsuario.Comentario + " - " +
                            dadosUsuario.Onde + " - " +
                            dadosUsuario.Assunto + " - " +
                            DateTime.ParseExact(dadosUsuario.Quando, "dd/MM/yyyy", null));
            pTh.ChamarThread(dadosUsuario.Nome, dadosUsuario.Email, dadosUsuario.DDD, dadosUsuario.Telefone, dadosUsuario.Regiao, absFileName, dadosUsuario.Comentario, dadosUsuario.Onde, dadosUsuario.Assunto, DateTime.ParseExact(dadosUsuario.Quando, "dd/MM/yyyy", null));

            return "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EscreverNoLog("Erro recebimento dos dados usuário Android");
            EscreverNoLog("Mensagem de Erro recebimento dos dados usuário Android: " + ex.Message);
            return "FALHA: " + ex.Message;
        }



    }

    public class DadosUsu
    {
        private string nome;
        private string email;
        private string ddd;
        private string telefone;
        private string regiao;
        private string nomearq;
        private string comentario;
        private string onde;
        private string assunto;
        private string quando;


       [DataMember(Name="Nome")]
        public string Nome
        {
            get { return nome; }
            set { nome = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name="Email")]
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name="DDD")]
        public string DDD
        {
            get { return ddd; }
            set { ddd = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name="Telefone")]
        public string Telefone
        {
            get { return telefone; }
            set { telefone = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name="Regiao")]
        public string Regiao
        {
            get { return regiao; }
            set { regiao = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name="NomeArq")]
        public string NomeArq
        {
            get { return nomearq; }
            set { nomearq = value; }
        }


        [DataMember(Name="Comentario")]
        public String Comentario
        {
            get { return comentario; }
            set { comentario = value; }
        }


        [DataMember(Name="Onde")]
        public string Onde
        {
            get { return onde; }
            set { onde = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name="Assunto")]
        public string Assunto
        {
            get { return assunto; }
            set { assunto = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name="Quando")]
        public string Quando
        {
            get { return quando; }
            set { quando =  value; }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at whats going across the wire, maybe with fidler?

Comment: I tried but I can not see the post on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter name in your operation (with body style `WrappedRequest`) is **dadosUsuario**. In the JSON you're creating in the Android code, the name of the property is **DadosUsuario**. The case is important - try changing it to `dadosUsuario` (or changing the parameter name in the operation to have its first character in upper case), and it should work.

On an unrelated note - you don't need to specify the `Name` property on the `[DataMember]` attributes since they're the same name as the properties of the class. It doesn't hurt, though.

Comment: I did it but the problem persists. Now both are dadosUsuario. Any other idea, I've searched all WCF questions here..no luck so far

Comment: It's working now!!! I forgot the:         [OperationContract]
        string ArqInfoAndroid(WCFService.UploadService.DadosUsu DadosUsuario);