# Android post a JSon object to WCF Rest receiving object with null parameter

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, rest

I having a problem with my android client trying to post a JSON class to my wcf rest service. Wcf is receiving the post, the object not null but the parameter inside the object always null.

this is my service code

```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
  UriTemplate = "uploadData")]
  int uploadDataPOST(UploadData uploadData);
```

this is my client code that call the service

```
 private String retriveUsers(String query) {
    String object = "uploadData";
    String url = constructUrlUpload(object);
    Log.d("json",query);
    String respons = httpRetriver.sendPost(url, query);
    if (respons != null) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), respons);
    }
    return respons;
}
```

UploadData class in client & server

```
    public class UploadData {

    public List<Fcustcard> lsCustVisits = new ArrayList<Fcustcard>();
    public List<Forder_h> lsMainOrder = new ArrayList<Forder_h>();
    public List<Forder_d1> lsDetailOrder = new ArrayList<Forder_d1>();
    public String id;
    public String cdDist;
    }
```

when i debug from my visual studio the client can call the wcf and UploadData object not null but all variabel is null.

I have see and try [Android post a JSon object to WCF receiving null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550117/android-post-a-json-object-to-wcf-receiving-null) but it not work
help me please

Comment: Can you check what's the JSON request data that's being sent using Fiddler. And you can try de-serializing the same JSON text using a simple piece of code like: var json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UploadData));
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            var newData = (UploadData)json.ReadObject(memoryStream); to see if you are able to successfully de-serialize the data?

Comment: are it is because deserialize?
i get the json and try it from c# to access the rest and it's work

Comment: i had try your code and it success. now i confuse why it not work when i call it using android